# How to change this kind color in VS1017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, settings

In VS2017, when you click the return type of method, all of the return points of the method will highlight:

[image]

I want change the highlight color, which item called in `Fonts and Colors`:

[image]

Comment: What: `bool` and `return` but not `string` and `if` ??

Comment: @TaW In VS2017 When you click return type of method, all return point highlight too, vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is not native VS functionality.

I remember when I was still using Resharper, this was a feature called [*Function Exits*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Navigation_and_Search__Navigate_from_Here__Function_Exits.html) (or *Context Exits*). Its colour is governed by the [ReSharper Context Exit](https://github.com/strayiker/vs-theme-darcula/blob/fd7bcbaff61eee5aa2ef5e1c40d71a0ddea89a80/darcula-vs-2017.vstheme#L1934) item on that list.

If it comes from an extension other than ReSharper, then you'll need to consult its documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This image shows how to edit color. But careful with what you are doing. color conflict will be a reason for code misunderstanding.

[Tools -> options -> then follow the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QvSB.png)

[image]

Comment: Tools => Options => Environment => Fonts and Colors And Search for Keywords in Display items.

Comment: first thanks for your answer. But this isn't keyword item, look those arrows, its about return point of method.

Comment: I tested the solution provided by Viraj. It works well, so you can check it again.

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT emm~you not understand this highlight, it's not about keywords, it's about context relate things, and i was wrong, it's not provided by VS, but Resharper.